# How to change dropdown text color of dark theme Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, drop-down-menu

I changed Eclipse theme to Dark. But I can't read any text in dropdown.

How can I change dropdown text color.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you @centic for changed body text ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Preferences/General/Appearance/Colors and Fonts/Contant Assist foreground color --> change to e.g. black.